# Service worker at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, worker

I recently discovered worker services in .net core 3.0, and this sounds perfect for a project that I'm currently working on.

At an interval, my service will collect (from database/file/whatever) tasks that need to be executed. I want to then queue through these tasks, and fire of Tasks for them to be executed on their own.

I cooked up my own home brew solution for this, but, as mentioned above, the worker service sounds like a better tried-and-tested solution to this problem.

I read several tutorials on the topic, and they all use pretty much the same approach; creating a new project from the wizard, and then explaining from there on. From the default template, I understand that this will spin off the worker service :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

However, I need some way to spin up these workers at run time, and I'm not able to find any guideline on how to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to spin up workers manually? I'd use 1 worker to watch for new incoming tasks, then have them handled in a DataFlow pipeline. Concurrency can be achieved there, pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @Fildor, thanks for your suggestion. I did some reading about DataFlow pipelines now. The concept seems great, for tasks that are dependent on each other, however, my tasks are not linked. They can all fire asynchronously at the same time. In such a case, would you still recommend I use that, or can I just, as per your suggestion, have one single Worker to collect and fire off new Tasks?

Comment: I'd do so, yes. I'd not use DataFlow if you don't have a pipeline. But starting Tasks will execute them on the Thread Pool anyway. You could also look into [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8) to restrict concurrency. I surely wouldn't take on the hassle to fire up new Threads and have them die if no longer needed by hand.

Comment: @Fildor, perfect, thanks. Yes, mistake there on my part for saying "thread" when I meant Task. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not take on the hassle to fire up `Threads` or `Workers` on demand.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Have one Worker Service as "`Watchdog`": Look for new "Tasks". If found, have them enqueued in some sort of Queue.
2. As you stated: Your Tasks are independent and do not require a "Pipeline". So I'd either start "`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`"s for each one or maybe have them handled through [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8)

Starting a CPU-bound Task will use a Threadpool Thread, so that should be sufficient for your usecase. If you need more control about the order of execution or degree of parallelism, you may consider DataFlow, although you'll probably have only one Node instead of a Pipeline. But that's up to you.